# convert csv import via pandas to separate columns

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv file that came into pandas like this:

csv file:

```
Date,Numbers,Extra, NaN  
05/17/2002,15 18 25 33 47,30,
```

Pandas input:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/owner/Downloads/file.csv’)e
#s = Series('05/17/2002', '15 18 25 33 47')
#s.str.partition(' ‘)
```

Output
                    Date   Numbers.  Extra

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of                  Draw Date  Winning Numbers  Extra   NaN. 
05/17/2002  15 18 25 33 47               30    NaN. 


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame’>  
RangeIndex: 1718 entries, 0 to 1717  
Data columns (total 4 columns):  
Date       1718 non-null object  
Numbers    1718 non-null object. 
Extra      1718 non-null int64  
 NaN       815 non-null float64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(2)  
memory usage: 53.8+ KB
```

How do I convert the non-null objects into two columns:

```
1 is a date  
1 is a list
```

It doesn’t seem to recognize `split` or `to.str.` or headings

Thanks

Comment: So to be clear on what you want. You want as an output a df with two columns, one of them is the date and all the rest in a list?

Comment: The last two columns are ok.  It says the first two are columns but they were one object for awhile.  I can't seem to convert them from objects to dates/list of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this. It specifies column 0 as a date column, and a converter for column 1:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',parse_dates=[0],converters={1:str.split})
>>> df
        Date               Numbers  Extra  NaN
0 2002-05-17  [15, 18, 25, 33, 47]     30
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much.  I have been trying a long time to get this to work and it works!  Thanks again Mark.

Comment: @Joan You're welcome!  Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer, too :^)